# STR_TO_DATE parsing of %b-%Y

Tags: mysql

I need to parse date in the format JAN-1980 to 1980-01-01 i.e. by adding the day as always being the first date of the indicated month.

How can I go about his?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat `-01` in your date, convert to date and then format back in your desired format e.g. below:

```
     DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('JAN-1980','-01'),'%b-%Y-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this,

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`colName`, '-01'),'%b-%Y-%d')
FROM table1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/851d1/2)

SOURCE

- [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)